# How to make row in gridview bold and regular programatically

Tags: c#, gridview

Hi I have written program in c# outlook where u can send, receive, reply and forward the mails in text format through database I used gridview to retrieve the mails. But the new task is how to mark the unread message as bold and read message as regular in text.

help needed

Comment: Are you referring to the GridView in ASP.NET or the DataGridView in Winforms?

Comment: i m using GridView in ASP.net

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through your rows by using.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Font = new Font(dataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
foreach(DataGridViewRow dg_r in myDataGridView.rows) 
{
  dg_r.DefaultCellStyle = style; // sets Row Style to Bold
}
```

Comment: The OP said GridView. The GridView is the Grid like control in ASP.NET not the DataGridView in Winforms.

Comment: I know. But afaik the syntax should be the same (just GridView instead of DataGridView)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have a collection of DataGridViewRows, rather it has GridViewRows, but more importantly than that, a GridViewRow doesn't have a DefaultCellStyle property. It has a Style collection which you can use to access the CSS attributes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But instead you can use: RowStyle and pass a TableItemStyle. Let's wait what he's using :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer to your question, but I think a better way to do this would be use a **ListView**. Then, you can use a **DataTemplate** for read items, and a different one for unread items. Then, just binding the set of mail items to this listview will cause the ListView to generate and display the UI for all the items. The main advantage of this will be that the UI will be *virtualized*, meaning UI items will be generated only as needed (when they scroll into view) and will be disposed automatically, keeping your UI responsive even when you have a huge number of items in the ListView.

You can then implement a **DataTemplateSelector**  to pick between the two DataTemplates, based on some of the attributes of the mail items.

Answer (score 0):

I am using telerik radgriw for asp.net (I don't know if it also work on asp grids)

on the ItemDataBound (rowdatabound in asp grids)

```
protected void Dtg_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem row = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    if (decimal.Parse(row["UniqueColumnName"].Text) > 0)
    {
        // iterate on cells
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            row.Cells[i].CssClass = "gridCellBoldRed";
    }
}
```

}

where gridCellBoldRed is a CSS calss (in my case its in ~/CSS/Style.css)

```
.gridCellBoldRed
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an asp:GridView, wouldn't this be enough?

```
 yourGrid.DataSource = yourDataTable;
 yourGrid.DataBind();

 foreach (GridViewRow item in yourGrid.Rows)
 {
      if (isRead/Unread condition)
      {
          item.Cells[yourCell].Text = 
          "<b>" + item.Cells[yourCell].Text + "</b>";                   
      }
 }
```