# Using Bold font for setting a Datagrid forecolor

Tags: c#, datagrid, fonts, bold

How do I make the font of a forecolor bold when I use this below code
dg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
How do I make it bold?

Thanks,
pooja

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (which you can also find in the designer.cs):

```
var dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
dataGridView1.Font = new Font("Arial",8.5F , FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this post answers your question:

[How to make row in gridview bold and regular programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073404/how-to-make-row-in-gridview-bold-and-regular-programatically-in-c-3-5)

cheers:)